# I can't seem to find the errors

Tags: javascript

*Even if there's no text in the field, it still directs to the email page.*

*First check whether anything has been entered in the required field. If there's no text in the textfield it should display an alert.*

```html
<html>
 <head>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    function checkForm(){        
     if (document.getElementById("lname").value == ""){          window.alert("Please enter your last name");
       document.getElementById("lname").focus();
       return false;
      }
      return true;
     }
            
  </script>
  <title>Testing your Javascript skills</title>
 </head>
 <body>
   <form action="mailto:me@fakeemail.com" onsubmit="checkForm()">
           
           <p>The fields marked with an asterisk (*) are required fields:</p>
           
           <p>*First Name: <input type="text" name="fname" id="fname" /></p>
           <p>*Last Name: <input type="text" name="lname" id="lname" /></p>
          
           <input type="submit" value="Enter Info" />
          </form>
          
 </body>
</html
```

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8664486/javascript-code-to-stop-form-submission

Comment: just add required attr on input form

Answer (score 1):

Pass the event object on submit handler and if last name is empty prevent the default behavior

```js
function checkForm(e) {
  if (document.getElementById("lname").value === "") {
    e.preventDefault();
    window.alert("Please enter your last name");
    document.getElementById("lname").focus();
    return false;
  }
  return true;
}
```

```html
<form action="mailto:me@fakeemail.com" onsubmit="checkForm(event)">
  <p>The fields marked with an asterisk (*) are required fields:</p>
  <p>*First Name: <input type="text" name="fname" id="fname" /></p>
  <p>*Last Name: <input type="text" name="lname" id="lname" /></p>
  <input type="submit" value="Enter Info" />
</form>
```